# Validating for N number of components for a delta deployment jenkins pipeline

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, jenkinsfile

I was trying to achieve delta deployment using sfdx-git-delta plug-in.
I can install the plugin in run time and plug-in was able to compare the two commit i'ds which i have mentioned in the command and generate the expected output of a delta_pkg and a package.xml which will be having the list of only changed components between the 2 commit i'ds.
but while triggering the validation using this delta_pkg & package.xml, i can see more components than required.

Ex : i have 8 components in the delta_pkg and package.xml but while triggering the validation it is taking 465 components